# Xcodebuild clean command fails in build script but works in terminal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bash, swift-framework

I have a build script written in Bash that is used to create an XCFramework for iOS. The script includes several `xcodebuild` commands, including a `clean` command to clean the workspace cache. When I run the script via SSH or manually in the terminal, it works perfectly fine without any errors. However, when I integrate the script into the Xcode build process as a build phase, the `xcodebuild clean` command fails with the following error:

```
Reason: Could not open workspace file at ~/apps/PHCore/PHCore/PHCore.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
```

I have verified that the path to the workspace file is correct and that the file exists. Additionally, I've confirmed that the file permissions should be set correctly . When I run the `xcodebuild clean` command manually in the terminal using the same path and options as in my script, it works without any issues.

Here is the relevant part of my build script:

```
rm -rf ./build &&\
rm -rf ./output &&\

xcodebuild \
    clean \
    -workspace PHCore.xcworkspace \
    -scheme PHCore
```

And here is the output of `ls -lG` in the directory where my workspace file is located:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 username  staff  6148 15 Feb 13:11 .DS_Store
drwxrwxrwx  12 username  staff   384 14 Feb 18:12 .git
drwxrwxrwx  12 username  staff   384 15 Feb 13:13 PHCore
drwxrwxrwx@  5 username  staff   160 15 Feb 13:20 PHCore.xcodeproj
drwxrwxrwx@  5 username  staff   160 14 Feb 17:37 PHCore.xcworkspace
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 username  staff  1284 14 Feb 17:35 build.sh
```

I replaced my username with "username"

I'm struggling to understand why the command fails only when run as part of the Xcode build process. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The backslashes in the `rm` lines look odd, but this is not the reason for the error. The error message says which file is missing. I would therefore do a `ls -r ~/apps/PHCore` just before the `xcodebuild` call and compare the output of  the working and the non-working case.

Comment: have you tried the usual routes: 1. reopen xcode 2. restart mac 3. delete derived data so you trigger the file indexing again?

Comment: I think it is pretty obvious what the issue is, I mean the error message says everything. Also this question was already answered many times here on Stackoverflow, please just do a little research before posting something ;)